# Botones de navegación en JSF2 y PrimeFaces al cerrar sesión

Tags: java, web, jsf, primefaces, sesiones

Tengo una aplicación web dinámica, que utiliza ***Java Server Faces 2.17 y PrimeFaces 5.1***.

Está montada en un *WebLogic 10* y esta se accede a él por medio de un servidor web llamado *Planet*.

El problema es que al realizar el **log out** de la aplicación, si se presionanan los botones de **backward** del navegador, se ven las pantallas anteriores, las cuales no se deben ver porque la sesión ya se murió, si selecciono alguna de las opciones, entonces, se regresa a la parte del *login*, pero lo que me piden es que no se vean las pantallas anteriores regresando con los botones de navegacion.

El código de mi cierre de sesión es el siguiente:

```
ExternalContext 
extContext=FacesContext.
getCurrentInstance().
getExternalContext();

setUrlLogout((String)
    configProps.get
        ("visor.oam.logout.url"));

session=(HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
session.invalidate();

//Codigo de prueba de termino de sesión
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().

extContext.redirect(getUrlLogout());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en la aplciación que tengo, es que despues de cerrar cesión, si yo navego con los botones del navaegador, se muesran todas las pantallas de todas las secciones donde accedí con la sesión activa, y aun se muestra la información de una consulta, por ejemplo, si yo iniciaba sesión, iba a la sección de usuarios, me mostraba la pantalla de usuarios y la lista de usuarios, después me regresaba a la sección proveedores y me mostraba la pantalla de proveedores y la lista de proveedores, y luego cerraba sesión. Al presionar el botón back o forward del navegador se me iban apareciendo esas pantallas con los datos consultados, era lo que no quería.

El problema no era la sesión, era la cache. Lo que había que hacer era decirle a la aplciación, **que no guardara la cache**, y se hace de esta forma.

Se crea una clase como esta:

```
public class ControlCachePhaseListener implements PhaseListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2759127646789250121L;
    public ControlCachePhaseListener() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.faces.event.PhaseListener#afterPhase(javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent)
     */
    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.faces.event.PhaseListener#beforePhase(javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent)
     */
    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FacesContext facesContext = arg0.getFacesContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext
                .getExternalContext().getResponse();
        response.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        // Stronger according to blog comment below that references HTTP spec
        response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");
        // some date in the past
        response.addHeader("Expires", "Mon, 8 Aug 2006 10:00:00 GMT");
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.faces.event.PhaseListener#getPhaseId()
     */
    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }
}
```

Después en el archivo **faces-config.xml** se agrega la siguiente etiqueta:

```
<lifecycle>
<phase-listener>com.myapp.util.ControlCachePhaseListener</phase-listener
</lifecycle>
```

Estas acciones eliminaron la cache, y ahora al cerrar sesión ya no vuelvo atrás, la respuesta la encontré en el siguiente sitio:

- [TurboManage: Disable Browser Caching in JSF](https://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2006/08/08/disable-browser-caching-in-jsf/)

Ojalá alguien quiera explicar mejor este procedimiento, me funcionó pero desconozco enteramente como funciona.

Veo que justamente en cada *phase*, si entiendo bien al cambiar de pantalla, después cada carga solicita eliminar la cache.

Answer (score 0):

Debes implementar dos cosas:

1. La salida de la aplicación y la destrucción del contexto.

Este es código de ejemplo:

```
FacesContext.
getCurrentInstance().
getExternalContext().
invalidateSession();

FacesContext.
getCurrentInstance().
getExternalContext().
redirect("/app/paginas/
ingreso_sistema.jsf");
```

En la *línea 1* se invalida la sesión, en la *línea 2*, se redirige a la página de inicio de sesión (aquí automaticamente el servidor y el navegador hacen una conexión y crean la nueva sesión).

2. Lo segundo que debes hacer es implementar que tus páginas tengan un control de sesión, algo sencillo puede ser colocar una variable booleaana, algo como esto:

```
public class 
ControladorSesion  {
    private Boolean booUsuAuto___t = false;

    public login(){
        booUsuAuto___t = validarUsuario(arg1,arg2);
    }
}
```

Cuando ejecutas el código del *paso 1* la debes poner en `false`.

Luego en tus páginas haces algo como esto:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered=#{controladorSesion.booUsuAuto___t}>
    Tu codigo de la pagina con la autorizacion
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup rendered=#{!controladorSesion.booUsuAuto___t}>
    Tu sesion ha caducado por favor inicia sesion.
</h:panelGroup>
```

Si lo vas a hacer así te recomiendo usar **plantillas** para no hacer lo mismo en cada una de tus páginas.

La otra alternativa es tener un filtro `http` y validar la misma variable.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tus comentarios, la verdad es que si se cierra la sesión pero  lo que permanecia ea el caché es por eso que me permitia navegar hacia atras y ver las opciones que habia consultado, aun que claro, si solicitaba algun request, entonces ya me mandaba a la pantalla de Login.  en un momento mas pongo la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Para manejar las sesiones de forma correcta en *JSF*, tiene anotaciones que pueden manejar dependiendo del alcance que le quieras dar los usas en cada `managedBean` de las páginas.

Son los siguientes:

1. `@ViewScoped`: Estará activa mientras el usuario tenga abierta la página y si la recarga matará la sesión y abrirá otra.
2. `@RequestScoped`: Vive exactamente el mismo tiempo que una solicitud `HTTP`. Por lo tanto, se cerrará al final de cada solicitud y se volverá a crear en cada nueva solicitud, perdiendo así todas las propiedades modificadas.
3. `@RequestScoped`: Solo se activa al realizar la petición, ahí mismo se acaba.
4. `@SessionScoped`: Esta dura mientras tengas abierto el navegador. Se cerrará la sesión.